# printf and gcc -O option change return value

Tags: c, gcc, return-value

i'm trying to understand how gcc -O option and printf can change return value.

in the code below `isTmax` is my function that return 1 if the input is the largest int value.

```
int isTmax(int x);
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", isTmax(0x7fffffff));
}

int isTmax(int x)
{
    int temp = x + x + 2;
    int result = !temp & (!!(~x));
    return result;
}
```

it worked perfectly when i compiled it without gcc option.

but with -O option, i got 0 for all integer values.

so i added printf to check values and then compiled it with -O option.

```
int isTmax(int x)
{
    int temp = x + x + 2;
    int result = !temp & (!!(~x));
    printf("x : %x, temp : %x, !temp : %x\n", x, temp , !temp); 
    return result;
}
```

And suddenly it's working again.

i want to know why the return value varies.

Comment: Read about [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @pmg to add, for Signed overflow. Using `0x7fffffff` here means already _at the edge_.

Comment: Specifically, the documentation points out that [signed integer overflows](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) may be completely optimized out ...

Comment: You can simplify this with `return x == INT_MAX;` which is in `limits.h`.

Comment: thx guys! i thought printf had changed something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, this is because of undefined behaviour.

Modern compilers can (ab)use undefined behaviour to simplify, shorten, and speed up the compiled code without violating any rules. I suggest you read that [excellent article](https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs) about the dangers of UB.

It's hard to know what exactly is going on because optimizer are becoming exceedingly complex, but here's a take on what the compiler might be doing with your function.

```
(1) int isTmax(int x)
(2) {
(3)     int temp = x + x + 2;
(4)     int result = !temp & (!!(~x));
(5)     return result;
(6) }
```

On line 3, you're adding together two signed integers. If your program only call this function once with `0x7fffffff`, the compiler already knows that the code only produces an integer overflow. There's a twist with that code ; since you add 2 to an overflowing operation, the compiler can assume that the value will be positive and greater than two for the sake of what comes next.

On line 4, `!temp` translate to the boolean constant `false` since temp is assumed to be a positive value. Next, the `and` ; since the left value is false (or 0), `result` always  end up being 0. If the result is always zero, the optimizer might as well remove all the variables and operations.

So essentially, after optimization, your function looks like :

```
int isTmax(int x)
{
    return 0;
}
```

By adding a `printf` inside the function, you're forcing the optimizer into de-optimizing, so you end up with the same code you get when you don't optimize your program.